# How to change a WCF service BodyStyle programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a WCF webservice and it's working pretty cool with some different clients.

Some clients consume it as **XML** and others as **JSON**.
To have this behavior I've designed all the services, as if they had a extension. If the extension is equal to **json**, then it return JSON, if not it returns XML.

The code bellow shows how I accomplish this behavior.

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "test.{PsFormat}")]
    public string test(string PsFormat) {
        DefineResponseFormat(PsFormat);
        return "test";
    }

    public static void DefineResponseFormat(string PsFormat)
    {
        OutgoingWebResponseContext context = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
        if (PsFormat.ToLower() == "json") {
            context.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
            context.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }
        else if (PsFormat.ToLower() == "wjson") {
            context.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
            context.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            // CHANGE BodyStyle TO WRAPPED
        }
        else {
            context.Format = WebMessageFormat.Xml;
            context.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        }
    }
```

The problem, is that I've always returned the JSON as if the WebGet Attribute BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, that is the default value. And now, I have a new client that need to sonsume it as if BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped. (Represented in the code above in the else if, with the extensions **wjson**.)

The question is: How do I change the BodyStyle value programmatically?

Comment: this post has similar question to yours - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8636a582-4c58-4ac0-a925-d7df5309423b/change-response-format-programmatically

Comment: look at both the answers carefully before coming to a conclusion on how you want to implement it